# SharePoint Online search customization with SPFx

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-search

I am planning to develop a SPFx WebPart for SharePoint online search, this should be exactly the way we used to customize the display template in SharePoint On-Premise search, could someone please give me some references or examples to start with. Thank you!!!

Comment: Did you check the modern search web parts, specifically the new ones made by Franck Cornu: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EECqOBWq3wo&feature=emb_title  .. you can also add your own JS code there to have your own look and feel.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I will check and update here...if you have already explored, can we add our own managed property and display the results conditionally?

Comment: Sure you can add your own managed property and play with the query to filter by it. I can add a more detailed answer if you like.

Comment: Sure, I would love to see...please add mate :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you can use the SharePoint Modern Search web part. You can download the package from this url: https://github.com/microsoft-search/pnp-modern-search/releases

Once you deploy the solution, it will provide you with few web parts (6 of them), for example, you can add the Refiners web part and it will provide you with a dropdown list for all the managed properties available for you to filter (you'll need to have the managed properties ready to be used):

[image]

You can connect it to the search results web part that comes with the solution using a web part property as well:

[image]

On the search results web part, you can filter it the way you want. You can also choose one of the predefined templates available based on the result type you're getting:

[image]

or you can edit the HTML that's generated through the way you want by having a custom template:

[image]

Comment: Thanks brother for the detailed answer.. you certainly deserve the upvote:-) actually few months back I had explored this web part, I am aware of this how to use this web part... but stack up in the custom html template part (black color template box)... there I want to conditionally display the search result... you know how to customize this html template?

Comment: The web part uses handlebars, so you can have an if condition inside the code to render things based on a specific condition.

Comment: Hi - this is the question I had raised regarding handlebar - just wanted to learn how we can add a custom attribute with a simple if condition in that - do you know this? https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/280360/customizing-the-pnp-people-search-handlebar-template-in-sharepoint-online

Comment: I was just moaning to myself how I loathed the lack of refiners in the modern experience. I will be looking into this ASAP, thanks!