# PnP Modern Search (version 3), hover functionally is not working on live persona card

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp

We are using the PnP modern search version 3 to display the people and using the solution given on, **hover functionally is not working on live persona card any more** (use to work - no code change)

Solution given | [Customizing the PnP people search handlebar template in SharePoint online](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/280360/customizing-the-pnp-people-search-handlebar-template-in-sharepoint-online/283694#283694?newreg=12a8d497294f400b8b029539903a056d)

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Karthik

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue but it started working magically this morning. :).
must have been something with the Microsoft API call that was throwing it off. Didn't have to change anything to fix it.

Comment: Thank for that Ritesh Sapkota, we did report this to MS.